# time command - what intervals do user and sys parameters measure?

Tags: linux, unix, time

I did a time on my script and this is what I got:

```
$ time <myscript>

real    7m5.458s
user    0m7.444s
sys     0m3.748s
$
```

which means that it ran for 7 minutes and 5.458 seconds.

What do the `user` and `sys` times tell me?

Answer (score 2):

The `real` time is the wall clock time. The `user` time is the amount of time spent executing the code while not waiting for resources (I/O, network, etc.). The `sys` time is the time spent by the kernel on behalf of the program, e.g., executing system calls.

Answer (score 0):

It's the amount of time actually executing code, as opposed to waiting on I/O or etc., in the program itself and in the kernel respectively.